# ordinary cohomology from equvariant cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-actions, equivariant-cohomology

Is it possible that the ordinary cohomology of a space can be obtained from its equivariant cohomology? 
action is algebraic torus action and space is nonsingular complete complex algebraic variety

If it is possible how can we do that? Are there any examples?

Comment: Equivariant cohomology in the sense of Borel, or Bredon?

Comment: in the sense of Borel.

Comment: Do you mean to a given action or what? An easy answer would be: yes, take $G=1$.

Comment: @Dan Yes given action is algebraic torus action and space is nonsingular and complete complex algebraic variety.

Answer (score 2):

For a compact, connected Lie group $G$ acting on a manifold $M$, you have a spectral sequence starting at $\text{E}_1^{p,q}\cong {\mathfrak S}^p({\mathfrak g}^{\ast})^G\otimes_{\mathbb R} \text{H}^{q-p}(M;{\mathbb R})$ and converging to $\text{E}_\infty^\ast\cong\text{H}^{\ast}_G(M)$. The $G$-space $M$ is called *equivariantly formal* if this sequence collapses at the $\text{E}_1$-page, in which case you can deduce that there is a (non-canonical) isomorphism $\text{H}^\ast_G(M)\cong\text{H}^\ast(M;{\mathbb R})\otimes_{\mathbb R} {\mathfrak S}({\mathfrak g}^\ast)^G$ of ${\mathfrak S}({\mathfrak g}^\ast)^G$-modules. In particular, you can recover $\text{H}^{\ast}(M;{\mathbb R})$ from $\text{H}^\ast_G(M)$ up to isomorphism by applying $-\otimes_{{\mathfrak S}({\mathfrak g}^\ast)^G} {\mathbb R}$. You can read about these things in

> ***Guillemin-Sternberg**: Supersymmetry and Equivariant de Rham Theory*, Chapter 6.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. but I don't know anything about spectral sequence. Are  there any alternative way for elementary  level? though I will look the book you suggest, thanks!

Comment: Dear @user365, I'm afraight I don't know a way to make this more elementary. The point is that you can find a bicomplex the total cohomology of which is equivariant cohomology, while the vertical homology is essentially the singular cohomology. Then it is an exercise of homological algebra to show that there is a sequence of successive differentials on this vertical homology such that when you pass to homology over and over again, you'll end up with the desired total cohomology. That's abstracted in the notion of a spectral sequence.